# Prove the direct product of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication. Then $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is the direct product of the circle group $T$ of unit complex numbers and the group $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ of positive real numbers under multiplication.

Comment: What's the question? Can you write up the definition of internal direct product?

Comment: @Berci See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product#Internal_and_External_direct_product)

Comment: Ah, no, there's another definition: two disjoint normal subgroups that generate the whole group. So we have to prove that $T\cap\Bbb R^+=\{1\}$ and that they generate the whole $\Bbb C^\times$.

Comment: @Berci They are (obviously) all equivalent.

Comment: @Berci Note that if $H,K$ are groups and we take $A=H\times K$ then $H^*=\{(h,1):h\in H\}$ and $K^*=\{(1,k):k\in K\}$ are isomorphic copies, and are both normal in $A$.

Answer (score 6):

Define $f:{\mathbb C}^{\times}\to T\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$ by $f(z)=(\frac{z}{|z|},|z|)$ and prove that this is an isomorphism of groups.

Actually $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is the *internal* direct product of the two since ${\mathbb C}^{\times}=T\mathbb{R}^{+}$ (write $z=\frac{z}{|z|}\cdot|z|$) and $T\cap\mathbb{R}^{+}=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: take the following "other-direction" map as that of YACP:

$$g: \Bbb T\times \Bbb R^+\to \Bbb C^*\;;\;\;g(e^{it},r):=re^{it}\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

i.e., the polar-coordinates representation for a non-zero complex number.